# How to open SSMS as a different user using username and NOT using email address?

Tags: windows-11, ssms

I am trying to run SSMS as a different user and it is not letting me run as a different user. It is asking for email address instead. How to get around this issue?
Thanks in advance.
[image: problem]

I have tried Holding on to shift and opening more options and then "run as different user"/

Comment: Try it like so `RUNAS /user:<domain>\<username> /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\SSMS.exe"`

Comment: Click “More Choices”

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use a modified shortcut. Clone the existing shortcut, and edit the Target to be something like

`C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /storecred /user:yourusername "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"`

When run, you'll be presented with a command prompt, into which you can type your password. The password will not be shown and will access the use of backspace, if you type it incorrectly.

**Note**: if the box doesn't prompt you for your password, your username isn't stored in the local credential store on the machine.